# jQuery .each() loop through array changes query string

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-string, each

I found a weird bug in my code and I can't find where it's going wrong. I'm looping through an array in jQuery with this function:

```
$.each(response, function(index, value) {
  console.log(value)
  $.get('/part_report_snippet', {
    part_request: value, 
    projekt_nummer: $('#project_id').val() 
  }, function(response){
    var $content = $(response);
    $grid.append($content).isotope('appended', $content);
  });
```

the array looks like this:

```
value = ["CA-S_INT-CM%MITTELKONSOLE", "CA-S_EXT-DM%HECK", "CA-S_INT-CM%BAUTEIL-S", "CA-S_INT-DM%BAUTEIL-M", "CA-S_INT-DM%BAUTEIL-S", "CA-S_INT-DM%EINZELSITZ", "CA-S_INT-DM%HINTERWAGEN", "CA-S_INT-DM%INTERFACEELEMENTE", "CA-S_INT-DM%ITAFEL", "CA-S_INT-DS%TÜR-HINTEN", "CA-S_INT-DS%TÜR-VORNE", "CA-S_ORG%MEETING", "CA-S_ORG%ORGANISATION", "CA-S_ORG%REVIEW"]
```

and the error:

> jquery.js:9175 GET http://uewin007:5000/part_report_snippet?part_request=CA-S_INT-CM%25MITTELKONSOLE&projekt_nummer=22135 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

The important is the piece with: `CA-S_INT-CM%**25**MITTELKONSOLE`. Where is the 25 coming from? I have absolutely no idea at all.

Thanks for your help

Comment: A 500 error means something has gone wrong in your server code. You need to debug that, not the JS.

Comment: The %25 is a url encoding of the "%" character in your input.

Answer (score 0):

> important is the piece with: CA-S_INT-CM%25MITTELKONSOLE where is the 25 coming from ?

That's perfectly normal. `%25` is the correct encoding of the `%` character in URI-encoding; characters in the GET params must be encoded as they're part of the URI of the request. `%` is special in URI-encoding as it introduces an encoded character (`%25` for `%`, `%20` for space, etc.) Your server will convert `%25` back to `%` when it URI-decodes it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: No -- er, well, probably not. :-) I was answering the question of "where does the 25 come from?"

Comment: oh wow i would have never guessed that. Is there any way how i can send it without the 25 ?

Comment: @mamolx: You're asking if you can send it through incorrectly. Probably, but I've never had reason to want to intentionally send incorrect URLs. Again: The correct way to send a `%` character in a GET param is `%25`.

Comment: what wonders me the most is that it works for all the 13 items in the array just not for 'CA-S_INT-CM%MITTELKONSOLE' and they all have the '%'

Comment: @mamolx: As Rory said in a comment on the question, it's almost certainly a problem in the server code, not the client code. I'll go further: It's almost certainly not the `%25`. You're focussing on that, but it's unlikely to be the problem. More likely some *other* issue is occurring. But the first thing I'd check is whether the server code is correctly URI-decoding the string. In most stacks, that's going to be automatic, but I'd still check...